# Formulation of matrix for FEM

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, finite-element-method

I am trying to use FEM to approximate the solution to the following BVP:
$-\frac{d}{dx}[a(x)u'(x)]+b(x)u(x)=f(x)$, on [0,1] where $u(0)=0$ and $u(1)=1$.

I am using the Galerkin method with hat functions:

${\varphi _j}$$\left( x \right)$ = $\left\{ {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}{\frac{{x - {x_{j - 1}}}}{h}}&{,x \in [{x_{j - 1}},{x_j}]}\\{\frac{{{x_{j + 1}} - x}}{h}}&{,x \in [{x_j},{x_{j + 1}}]}\\0&{,x \notin [{x_{j - 1}},{x_{j + 1}}]}\end{array}} \right.$ , j=1,$\cdots$ ,m.

To start I have set $u(x)=\sum_{j=1}^{m} \delta_j\varphi_j(x)$, $ $ $\rho(x)=-\frac{d}{dx}[a(x)u'(x)]+b(x)-f(x)$, used the product rule to evaluate $-\frac{d}{dx}[a(x)u'(x)]$, and required $\int_{0}^{1}\rho(x)\varphi_k(x)dx = 0, k=1,\cdots,m$.

After some simplifications this gives me the following integral:
$\int_{0}^{1}\sum_{j=1}^{m}\delta_j[-a'(x)\varphi_j'(x)-a(x)\varphi_j''(x)+b(x)]$  $\varphi_k(x)dx-\int_{0}^{1}f(x)\varphi_k(x)dx = 0$

where the $\delta_j$ are the weights we are solving for.

I then simplified the RHS using integration by parts as follows:
$-\int_{0}^{1}a(x)\varphi_j''(x)\varphi_k(x)dx = -a(x)\varphi_k(x)\varphi_j'(x)\Big|_{0}^{1}+\int_{0}^{1}a'(x)\varphi_j'(x)\varphi_k(x)dx + \int_{0}^{1}a(x)\varphi_j'(x)\varphi_k'(x)dx$ (***)

From the boundary conditions we know $-a(x)\varphi_k(x)\varphi_j'(x)\Big|_{0}^{1}=0$.

After plugging these two results into (***) above I obtained:
$\int_{0}^{1}\sum_{j=1}^{m}\delta_j[a(x)\varphi_j'(x)\varphi_k'(x)+b(x)\varphi_j(x)\varphi_k(x)]dx-\int_{0}^{1}f(x)\varphi_k(x)dx = 0$

Is there a mistake somewhere? My professor was in a rush to cover FEM before the semester ended and he skipped the intermediate steps I have attempted to fill in. His result was not the same as mine and I do not see an error. The semester has ended so I can't go to his office hours for help but I was not able to implement the method and I think my derivation for the matrix A is the cause.

I apologize if my post is a little hard on the eyes. I fought with Latex for over an hour on this post! I've never used it before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your way of arriving at the resulting matrix equation is... strange (read: non-standard and, hence, possibly leading to false conclusions). However, the resulting set of equations seems to be almost correct: the only mistake I could spot is that you are not handling the nonhomogeneous Dirichlet condition at $x=1$ in any way.

Using your notation, let us define (the symmetric) matrices $A, B \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times m}$ and vectors $f, u \in \mathbb{R}^m$ as
$$
\begin{align*}
A_{ij}&=\int_0^1 a(x)\varphi_i' \varphi_j'\,\mathrm{d}x, \\
B_{ij}&=\int_0^1 b(x) \varphi_i \varphi_j\,\mathrm{d}x, \\
f_i &= \int_0^1 f(x)\varphi_i \,\mathrm{d}x, \\
u_i &= \delta_i.
\end{align*}
$$
Suppose that you included all mesh points (also $x=0$ and $x=1$) in your matrices while assembling and let $i=m$ correspond to $x=1$ and $i=1$ correspond to $x=0$.
Then your matrix equation reads
$$
(A+B)u=f
$$
with the extra requirement $u_1=0$ and $u_m=1$.
Then you can write
$$
\begin{bmatrix} u_1 \\ u_2 \\ \vdots \\ u_{m-1} \\ u_m \end{bmatrix}
= \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ u_2 \\ \vdots \\ u_{m-1} \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}
= \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ u_2 \\ \vdots \\ u_{m-1} \\ 0 \end{bmatrix} +
\begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ \vdots \\ 0 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}
$$
and, hence,
$$
(A+B)\begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ u_2 \\ \vdots \\ u_{m-1} \\ 0 \end{bmatrix} = f - (A+B)\begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ \vdots \\ 0 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}.
$$
Finally you may simply drop the first and the last equations in the system since they are automatically satisfied.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I should have made my notation more clear. For this problem I am assuming there are $m+2$ points. $m$ here stands for the number of elements (the number of $\varphi_k(x)$).The point $x_0$ and the point $x_{m+2}$ are omitted from the system I obtained. The actual formula fomula for a given $u(x_k)$ is the affine function $u(x_k) = \varphi_0(x) +\sum_{i=1}^{m}\delta_i\varphi_i(x)$ where $\varphi_0 = \frac{1}{h}(x-x_{m+1})$ if $x_m \leq x \leq x_{m+1}$ and $\varphi_0 = 0$ elsewhere. When you say my method was non-standard, how would you propose I derive the matrix?

Comment: What I merely wanted to point out that due to nonzero Dirichlet condition at $x=1$ you get an additional contribution to the load vector (as you can see from my post). It does not matter how you number the mesh points. If you don't include such a contribution you will get a wrong result. Usually when you derive the weak form for a specific problem, you do not start opening derivatives using products rule and then somehow get rid of terms like $a'(x)$. Instead you multiply by a test function and then integrate by parts to balance derivatives. That's why I said your way is non-standard.